# Why is this $_GET empty after form is submitted by GET, and why is a "?" appended to URL on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here is an SSCCE demonstrating my problem. At the top of the page,  the `$_GET` is printed. When the page is first loaded, it is understandable that an empty array `Array()` will be printed.

But the `form`'s `action` attribute has an empty value, which means the page is submitted to itself. The value of `method` is `GET`. So the form is submitted by GET.

So when the form is submitted to the page itself by GET, now the `$_GET` array printed at the top of the page must NOT be empty. Oh, but it is! And that is the question.

When the form is submitted,

1. the `$_GET` array printed at the top of the page is empty. `Array ()`
2. A **`?`** is appended to the URL. For example, before the form submission, the URL of the page was **`http://localhost/Test/index.php`**. After the form is submitted, the page reloads and the URL becomes **`http://localhost/Test/index.php?`**

**The question is why? and how do I fix this.**

```
<?php 
print_r($_GET);//check
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css"/>
    <script src="<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="get">

        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="validate" />
            <label for="nameInput">Name: </label>
        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-light waves-effect">Submit Form</button>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `Name attribute` is missing in `input type`

Comment: You are not sending any data with that form. You need to add `name` attribute to input elements.

Comment: name attribue missing

Comment: add `name` attributes to `input`. `?` added due to `GET` method, if don't want it. use `POST` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The $_GET array printed at the top of the page is empty.

This is because you need to provide a `name` attribute on the `input` for it to be added to the key/value pair data sent in the request:

```
<input type="text" id="nameInput" class="validate" name="foo" />
```

> A `?` is appended to the URL. For example, before the form submission, the URL of the page was `http://localhost/Test/index.php`. After the form is submitted, the page reloads and the URL becomes `http://localhost/Test/index.php?`

That's because that is how a GET request works; the information is appended to the URL as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Once you send the request with the `name` attribute added to the `input`, the URL will become:

```text
http://localhost/Test/index.php?foo=[value]
```

Answer (score 1):

The $_GET is empty because your input have no name.
The "?" is put by default when you send a form by GET : http://url.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&...

Answer (score -1):

Is there some kind of syntax error of your code?

```
<script src="<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>"></script>
```

Please check you syntax first.